# How do I add a '+1' link in a Rails 3 app that when clicked increases the Upvotes value by 1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, controller

I'm new to programming.

I generated an Ideas scaffold. The model has fields: Description (string), Upvotes (integer), Downvotes (integer).

All the normal actions in the ideas_controller.rb work - Index, Show, New, Edit, Create, Update, Destroy.

Instead of telling you the ways I've tried to do the following, I'll just ask:

How do I add a '+1' link next to the 'Show', 'Edit', 'Destroy' links that when clicked increases the Upvotes value by 1 for that idea?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT (With "Skydreamer's" help, I figured it out!)**

I adjust the routes.rb to:

```
   resources :ideas do
     member do
       get 'upvote'
     end
   end
```

I add the following to the ideas index.html.erb:

```
<td><%= link_to '+1', upvote_idea_path(idea) %></td>
```

Note: if you don't include the **(idea)**, you'll get an error like this:

> **No route matches {:action=>"upvote", :controller=>"ideas"}**

I add the following to the ideas_controller.rb:

```
    def upvote
      @idea = Idea.find (params[:id])
      @idea.upvotes = @idea.upvotes + 1
      @idea.save
      redirect_to(ideas_url)
    end
```

Comment: `@idea.upvotes += 1` is more idiomatic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the next lines, I'll say upvote but that works the same for downvote.

First, create a member route `upvote`, then you can link from your show view to the new action using `upvote_idea_path`.

Second, create an action `upvote` in the controller which increases the vote count by 1 and you're done. That's all.

Comment: Can I do it from the Index view instead of from the Show view?

Comment: Yeah, obviously, you can, like any other route.

Comment: Would you put the upvote action in the ideas controller? What does it mean to create a member route vs a collection route? Could you show some example code?

Comment: Member view means for instance `ideas/[id]/upvote` while collection means rather `ideas/upvote`. You can see how to set up one [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) (section 2.9). The action go in the idea controller and can access the id of the ressource.

Comment: thanks so much for your help! Can you take a look at the updated code and see what I screwed up? It's still not working and I'm not sure why. (The rails server is running in development mode, but I still restarted just in case.) Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I haven't precised it. You have to precise which idea you want to upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this functionality with the [thumbs_up](https://github.com/brady8/thumbs_up) gem. It is also Rails 3 compatible.

Comment: I'm always stunned of all the interessant plugins the rails community provide ! This one seems great.